create an apex email handler class
once we will get an email we need check that email template format in correct format... example Please update all Salesforce records to reflect family violence.
all these information in between the brackets & if there are multiple accounts then these accounts should be [123456, 678901] in this format only... not this format [123456/567890].. and no records outside of these brackets []123456
my requirement is that, when you get an email first check the email format is correct or not.. means all the information is in brackets or not... if not then send reply to the business saying that correct the format and send email again.... once we will get correct formatted email then we will check the ACCOUNT, PERSON ID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, PHONE NO and based on that we are going to mark account as saftey account....

I write one apex class for that but wont be able to achieve my requirement
